# Powershell -regex , how to replace all to "Ver" word

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I'm trying to make a regex which helps me to replace all of string to "Ver" word.

example strings:

```
$a=BIOS Date: 12/02/13 10:59:34 Ver: 11.00.10
$b=BIOS Date: 06/10/09 10:59:34 Ver: 05.03.56
$c=BIOS Date: 03/12/03 10:59:34 Ver: 03.01.10
```

and I need the result:

```
$a=Ver: 11.00.10
$b=Ver: 05.03.56
$c=Ver: 03.01.10
```

I tried this one, but it doesn't work in PowerShell.

```
[^/]++[^Ver]++
```

Comment: `-replace '.*\s(Ver:.*)', '$1'`

Comment: Thanks very lot, it works, can you explain me that ?? .* - all of marks
\s() - to words 
Ver: - Ver:
.* - all of marks      - thats all ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
-replace '.*\s(Ver:.*)', '$1'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/URXsra/1)

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible,
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(Ver:.*)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1`): `Ver:` followed with any 0+ chars other than newline, as many as possible. This is the value that remains after replacing with the `$1` replacement backreference.